# e-sign in pdf file, makes multiple paged pdf to single page with same content

Tags: ios, pdf, integrate, electronic-signature

Am trying to sign my pdf file which is multiple paged, by fetching the signature drawn in UIView to my pdf file, but the problem I face is, after signing the pdf, signature is integrated with the pdf file where all the pages in the pdf file is displayed in a single page as a pdf file.(ex if 8 pages are there in a pdf file, then all 8 pages are displaying as a single page along with the signature). The output of the pdf file with signature integrated, is as below

[image: output of the code]

Codes used for fetching the image from document directory and integrating with the pdf file is,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[webView reload];

UIWebView *webView;
webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, 320, 460)];

NSString *path1;
path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"typo_tips" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectoryPath;
NSURL *targetURL;

documentDirectoryPath  = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"typo_tips.pdf"];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:documentDirectoryPath error:&error];

NSLog(@"path1 value is %@ \n",path1);
NSLog(@"docu dir path is %@ \n",documentDirectoryPath);



if (entered==1)//"entered==1", after save button clicked in signviewcontroller 
{
targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath];


}
else     targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];


 if (entered==1)
{


CFURLRef url;
url = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectoryPath]);
CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument;
myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);

// Create PDF context
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, NULL, NULL);     //(CFURLRef)outputURL
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

int totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument);
NSLog(@"no. of pages in pdf is %d \n",totalPages);

for (int currentPage = 0; currentPage < totalPages; currentPage++)
{

CGContextDrawPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocument, page));
//"page" is current pdf page to be signed

    if (page == currentPage)
    {

    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];// "image.png" is the saved user's signature in document directory

    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, image.CGImage);
    }

}


// Clean up
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);

}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Can any one help me, how to display the pdf page separately along with the e-signature integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Create PDF context
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, NULL, NULL);     //(CFURLRef)outputURL

int totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument);
NSLog(@"no. of pages in pdf is %d \n",totalPages);

for (int currentPage = 0; currentPage < totalPages; currentPage++)
{
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 
        CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocument, page));
    //"page" is current pdf page to be signed

    if (page == currentPage)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];

        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, image.size.width, image.size.height);

        CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageRect, image.CGImage);
    }

    // Clean up
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
}

CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
```

In your for loop you have to create a new PDF page for each page in the source file. I moved these lines inside the for loop:

```
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);
```

and also the corresponding cleanup code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a webview to display it Reader which uses iOS built in PDF reading classes.

https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Failing that, try adjusting the zoom levels on your UIWebview. Unfortunately UIWebview has limited options because its just a web container.

Comment: I have updated my question with my output image, just have a look and help me how to display as a multiple paged pdf file. Actually zooming is not an issue about my question.